# How to check multiple conditions by passing parameters to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, parameters

I am facing a problem in procedure the situation is.

I have to check multiple conditions using if else in the procedures, which is taking more time to execute.

The procedure structure as follows

```
create procedure sp_CheckMultipleconditions
    @Con1 varchar(10) = null,
    @con2 int = null,
    @con3 int = null,
    ..
    @Con6 varchar(10) = null
as
BEGIN
   if(@con1 is not null)
   begin
      ----- statement ----
   end

   else if(@Con2 is not null)
   begin
      ----- statement ----
   end
   .
   .
   .
   else if(@Con2 is not null and @Con3 is not null)
   begin
     .
     .
     .
   end
END
```

In this way I wrote the procedure it is having 36 if else conditions which is taking more time, can anyone please suggest a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

if second variable is null then it will return `true`

```
select * from table
where (mycol1=@Con1 or @Con1 is null)
and (mycol2=@Con2 or @Con2 is null)
and (mycol3=@Con3 or @Con3 is null)
and (mycol4=@Con4 or @Con4 is null)
and (mycol5=@Con5 or @Con5 is null)
```